# How to change flex-layout using Angular2 animations?

Tags: angular, animation, typescript, angular2-animation

I made my first steps in *@angular/animations* with help of official tutorial. I added reqired libraries and i create my first animation. I already know what transition and state is. I can create simple animations (changing background colors and changing size of elements.

I use *@angular/flex-layout* library in my project to create neat page layout. And here comes the question: **How can I animate increasing and decreasing width of elements my flex layout?** For example:

[image: simulate of animation states]

I have 3 "columns" on my page:

1. In the **first state** their width is: 38%, 52%, 10% of container
2. and in the **second state** their width is: 50%, 25%, 25%

just like in the picture (these are the same columns in other states)

Question: How should I make a transitions to animate changing width of columns? Which methods and attributes can I use? What code should look like?

=====

@EDIT:

I publish fragment of my HTML code to present which attribute I want change (**fxFlex**)

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="flex-container"
    fxLayout="row"
    fxLayout.xs="column"
    fxLayoutAlign="end none"
    fxLayoutAlign.xs="end none" class="container-style">

    <!-- first column -->
    <div class="flex-item" fxFlex="38%" fxShow.xs="false" class="one" [@oneState]="state"></div>

    <!-- second column -->
    <div class="flex-item" fxFlex="52%" class="two" [@twoState]="state"></div>

    <!-- third column -->
    <div class="flex-item" fxFlex class="three"></div>
</div>
```

for **app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('oneState', [
      state('inactive', style({
        //I have no idea what I should use to change fxFlex attribute!
        //Style? Maybe, something else?
      })),
      state('active',   style({
        //I have no idea...
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
    ]),
    trigger('twoState', [
      state('inactive', style({
        //I have no idea what I should use to change fxFlex attribute!
        //Style? Maybe, something else?
      })),
      state('active',   style({
        //I have no idea...
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
    ]),
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  state: string = 'inactive';

  toggleMove() {
    this.state = (this.state === 'inactive' ? 'active' : 'inactive');
    console.log(this.state);
  }

}
```

I know that I can change styles of div in simple way. But i **don't want to change style**. I would like to **change a fxFlex attribute** of element.

Anyone can help me? Is it possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need angular animations for this, you can create a `<col>` component, like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "col",
  styles:[`
  :host{
    transition: width 300ms linear;
    display:block;
  }
  `],
  template:`<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class ColComponent{
  @Input()
  @HostBinding("style.width")
  fxFlex:string;
}
```

and then use it in your app template like `<col fxFlex="50%"></col>` (note that you can use another `selector` like `"div[flexible]"` or whatever...

I created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0E4y9W9pr0VUUYTUs9q4?p=preview)

Comment: Oh, then you don't need to use angular animations :D

Comment: Yo n00dl3! :D Thanks for your interest in the topic. I voted up your answer, but it isn't solution. It work only when I turn off FlexLayoutModule from my project. I wrote that I want to use @angular/flex-layout library to style page layout my project. Have you another ideas?

Comment: You can do this with a directive with a selector on `[FxFlex]`, it's more or less the same except you will need to set the styles directly on the element instead of a stylesheet...